# Mk 170 wet tile saw

Tags: tile

My "mk170" wet tile saw, been sitting in my father's shed unused for years, the pump works, the blade won't spin. Checked everything, still no spin? Please help I need to rip 3x6 subway tiles to 3/4".

Comment: Sounds like the motor is struck or a bearing.  Will need to take it apart.  Maybe some light oil might help, but it will depend on how it was put away.  Might need a new motor if it is bad.

Comment: I'd be spraying some WD40 onto the spindles from both sides, and do it for several days. A bit of brute force with a mole wrench after might get it moving. Don't plug it in until it's at that stage!

Comment: The dangers of being a tool with spinny parts used wet, and put away for years. Can you turn the blade by hand?

Comment: If it was a moist / damp place then the armature of the motor could have corroded and "grown" so it is now basically solidly fixed to the field...